# Is it some kind of bugs that cause Adobe Illustrator to have issue with colors?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, hex

I was trying to change the fill color of my grouped objects.
I tried to input a hex color code I copied from the internet but it didn't work at first try. Instead, I got a grey hue.

Even though, It seemed to be fixed after I chose one of the system default colors, and then retried inputting the hex code again.

[image]

I'm curious, is it some kind of bugs? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are working in grayscale. You can fix this easily from the *Color* panel.

Go to **Window → Color** (<kbd>F6</kbd>)

Click on the little dropdown menu

Switch your color mode from 'Grayscale' to 'RGB' (or 'Web Safe RGB' for HEX).

<sub>Also, if you would just click on any (non Black or White) color in your swatches, that would switch it back as well.</sub>

---

In general, I prefer to use the color panel for colors as opposed to double clicking on the fill color.

This would also avoid the problem in the future, as you'd see something was up right away.

Comment: Oh yeeeaahh, I forgot that color panel. #facepalm